# Loop through array and replace text inside curly baces

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, button, click

Hope someone can help, I want to stitch together text from different textboxes and then replace anything with the placeholder {xxx} with objects from an array. The final text is outputted into 'Text_area_3'.

I then want to be able to click a button which then cycles through the array one at a time replacing the placeholder each time.

Here's what I've got so far, but I'm stuck trying to cycle through the array with button clicks.

```
function concatenate(){
    document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML =
    document.getElementById("text_area_1").value + " " + 
    document.getElementById("text_area_2").value;

 document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = 
   document.getElementById("text_area_3").value;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  var arr = ["One","Two","Three"];
  var index = 0;
  $('#next').click(function(){ 
    index = (index + 1) % arr.length ;
 });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what you have already tried and explain the parts where you are having troubles. in this way it will be easier for someone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over an array in javascript try the jquery $.each function.  Here is an example from there documentation.

```
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```

where value is 52 and 97 and index is 0 and 1.